# few vagrant boxes in one project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

I want to use 2 vagrant boxes with 2 different environments in one project. I tried add 2 boxes via:

```
vagrant box add first_box http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
vagrant box add second_box http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
```

and switch between them via:

```
vagrant init first_box
vagrant init second_box
```

But they are the same - when I create test file in one box, I see it in other.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if I miss something here, but isn't it sufficient in your case to describe 2 machines in your Vagrantfile like so:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

  config.vm.box = "lucid32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box"

  # define box #1
  config.vm.define "node1" do |cfg|
    cfg.vm.network "10.23.5.11"
    cfg.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
      puppet.manifest_file = "node1.pp"
    end
  end

  # define box #2
  config.vm.define "node2" do |cfg|
    cfg.vm.network "10.23.5.12"
    cfg.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
      puppet.manifest_file = "node2.pp"
    end
  end

end
```

Now you can easily start both nodes with

```
vagrant up
```

or one of them with

```
vagrant up <nodename>
```

and stop them respectively with the 'halt' command. You can ssh into them with

```
vagrant ssh <nodename>
```

or directly under the configured IP address.

If you don't need puppet, just leave these lines out, otherwise you can manage the different provision srcipts in the manifests folder.